# How to add multiple print functions into one string

Tags: python

I have multiple function that instead of returning they print a certain string I can’t put the whole function but that’s what they end up doing I want to take all of these function and make them into a single string.

```
Here’s an example of what one function would print and what I tried 

    def print_names(lst):
        print(name) 
    def print_id(lst):
        print(id)
    
    lst = [name, not_name, not_name,id] 
    print_id(lst) + print_name(lst) 

Doing this I get the error unsupported operand types for +: none type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are trying to add together the returned value for your `print_names` and `print_id` methods.

Since there is no return statement in these methods, the return value will be `None` and you cannot apply the `+` operator to the none type.

If you want to print these two items in your list together as one string, you would need to return the items, add them together, and print that:

```
lst = ['name', 'not_name', 'not_name','id']
def get_name(lst):
    return lst[0]
def get_id(lst):
    return lst[3]

print get_id(lst) + get_name(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok you should do it like this

```
def print_names(lst):
    return lst[0]
def print_id(lst):
    return lst[3]

lst = [name, not_name, not_name,id] 
id_and_name = print_names(lst) + print_id(lst)
```

after that you will be able to print the "id_and_name" together

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to return the Values, it would make it easier

```
def print_names(lst):
    #rest of the function
    return name 
def print_id(lst):
    #rest of the function
    return id

lst = [name, not_name, not_name,id] 
print(print_id(lst) + print_names(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions return `None`, unless stated otherwise. `print_id` and `print_name` are returning both returning `None` and you are trying to add `None + None` which is not possible.

You can just return strings, concatenate (join) the two strings, and print that new string:

```
def get_name(lst):
   return str(lst[0])

def get_id(lst):
   return str(lst[3])

print(get_name(lst) + " " + get_id(lst))
```

or f-strings:

```
print(f"{get_name(lst)} {get_id(lst)}")
```

Or, use a dictionary so you dont need to index the data:

```
user_data = {
    "name": "tom"
    "id": 123456
}

print(f"{user_data["name"]} {user_data["id"]}")
```